# Incrementing textfield values with arrow keypresses in JQuery

Tags: jquery, logic

I have an input box with a numeric value in it. When the user press ARROW_UP once, the number should be incremented by one. When the user press a long ARROW_UP, the number should be incremented with a bigger value.

I am looking for a jQuery solution, but a plain JavaScript solution is fine as well.

Comment: The way this is worded might be giving people the impression that you want something written for you, when in fact you're really just looking for a library call. Please consider revising your question a bit.

Comment: long arrow up key = the answer will be to increment as long is KEY_DOWN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//I have not tested it, but it should work or you have to do some minor adjustments.
// to make it numeric only

$("#txt").keydown(function(event){

```
    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
        // dont do anything
    }
    else {
        if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
```

});

// for arrow keys

$("txt").keypress(function(event) {

```
var intVal = 0;

if ($("txt").val() != '')
{
   intVal = $("txt").val();
}


if ( event.which == 38 ) 
{
   $("txt").val(intVal + 1);
}

if ( event.which == 40 )  
{
   $("txt").val(intVal - 1);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo's YUI has controls for this, so does ExtJS.  If you want to tool your own, I suggest looking up jQuery's or ExtJS's KeyMap and KeyNav capabilities.